# Linq join 2 entities by dateFrom and dateTo

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Lets say I have these entities :

```
flights: [
  {
    ...
    "flightId": 1,
    "dateFrom": "2023-03-01",
    "dateTo": "2023-03-01",
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    "flightId": 2,
    "dateFrom": "2023-03-03",
    "dateTo": "2023-03-03",
    ...
  }
]

hotels: [
  {
    ...
    "bookId": 1,
    "dateFrom": "2023-03-01",
    "dateTo": "2023-03-03",
    ...
  }
]
```

And my goal is to have something like :

```
[
 {
   date : "2023-03-01",
   flights: [
       {
          "flightId": 1
       }
   ], 
   hotels: [
       {
          "bookId": 1,
       }
   ]
 },
 {
   date : "2023-03-02",
   flights: [], 
   hotels: [
       {
          "bookId": 1,
       }
   ]
 },
 {
   date : "2023-03-03",
   flights: [
       {
          "flightId": 2
       }
   ], 
   hotels: [
       {
          "bookId": 1,
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

May I know how I can join / group those 2 using LINQ or any method in C#, using both dateFrom & dateTo, including those that dates aren't equal and in between as well ?

So it will show every date with either flights / hotels on it.

I'm fairly new to c# / .net so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit : Here's my table

```
------User------
| Id | Name    
----------------
| 1  | John Doe
----------------

Flight---------------------------------
| Id | DateFrom   | DateTo     | UserId
---------------------------------------
| 1  | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-01 | 1
---------------------------------------
| 2  | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 | 1


Hotels---------------------------------
| Id | DateFrom   | DateTo     | UserId
---------------------------------------
| 1  | 2023-03-01 | 2023-03-03 | 1
```

Comment: For a given date, do you want both the elements where the `dateFrom` attribute matches, and also those where the `dateTo` attribute matches, mixed together? So each flight and hotel will be twice in the final result (once in the list corresponding to `dateFrom` and once in the one for `dateTo`)

Comment: Yes correct, likely show every date with either flights / hotel

Comment: The dataset is too limiting to make the example clear, each set should include more than 1 match. The dates uses should also be disconnected to show the boundary behaviours, for instance what about flights that span multiple dates and what it should look like when there are no flights or hotels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s `FullJoin()` extension:

```cs
var flights = new[] {
    new Flight(1, From: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-12"), To: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-15")),
    new Flight(2, From: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-14"), To: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-17"))
};
var hotels = new[] {
    new Hotel(3, From: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-10"), To: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-13")),
    new Hotel(4, From: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-11"), To: DateTime.Parse("2023-01-14"))
};

var flightsByDay = flights
    .SelectMany(f => Days(f.From, f.To), (flight, day) => (flight, day))
    .GroupBy(f => f.day, f => f.flight);

var hotelsByDay = hotels
    .SelectMany(h => Days(h.From, h.To), (hotel, day) => (hotel, day))
    .GroupBy(h => h.day, h => h.hotel);
    
var result = flightsByDay
    .FullJoin(
        hotelsByDay,
        f => f.Key,
        h => h.Key,
        fs => (day: fs.Key, flights: fs.ToArray(), hotels: Array.Empty<Hotel>()),
        hs => (day: hs.Key, flights: Array.Empty<Flight>(), hotels: hs.ToArray()),
        (fs, hs) => (day: fs.Key, flights: fs.ToArray(), hotels: hs.ToArray()))
    .OrderBy(x => x.day);

static IEnumerable<DateTime> Days(DateTime from, DateTime to) => Enumerable
    .Range(0, 1 + to.Subtract(from).Days)
    .Select(offset => from.AddDays(offset));

public record Flight(int Id, DateTime From, DateTime To);
public record Hotel(int Id, DateTime From, DateTime To);
```

If you got LINQPad this is what you'll see for `result.Dump()`:

[image]

Comment: Hello, fortunately your answer can help achieve my result entities. But how can I replace Item1, Item2, Item3 keys with days, flight, hotels ?

Comment: Ah no worries, I just have to select to my new entities after order by day. Appreciate the help, have a good day :)